# Count the corners, edges and faces of a cut cube

Tags: code-golf

[Coming from this sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17058/59642)

This is inspired from an 8th graders math test

## Intro

We have a cube with following corners

```
A(0, 0, 0)
B(1, 0, 0)
C(1, 1, 0)
D(0, 1, 0)
E(0, 0, 1)
F(1, 0, 1)
G(1, 1, 1)
H(0, 1, 1)
```

This cube clearly has 8 corners, 12 edges and 6 faces. If we now cut off corner G, such that our cut plane goes exactly through the middle of each adjacent original edge, we add 2 new corners, 3 new edges and one new face.  Please enjoy this hand drawn piece of art, for better clarification

[image]

## Input

Given a list of corners (in this example identified by A-H), that will  be cut off, compute the new number of corners, edges and faces.

You make take the input in any form you like, <strike>as long as it responds to the same corners</strike> (e.g. instead of A-H you can use 1-8 or 0-7, you can assume it to be a list, csv, whatever)

You can assume the list to be distinct (every corner will appear once at most), but it may be empty. The list will never contain non existing corners.

## Output

Output three numbers corresponding to the number of corners, edges and faces. Output as a list is explicitly allowed.
Trailing whitespaces are allowed

Examples

```
{}        ->  8, 12,  6 (empty list)  
{A}       -> 10, 15,  7  
{A,C}     -> 12, 18,  8   
{A,C,F}   -> 14, 21,  9  
{A,B,C}   -> 12, 19,  9  
{A,B,C,D} -> 12, 20, 10
```

Finally, this is codegolf, thus the shortest answer in bytes wins. Please refrain from standard loopholes.

Comment: Interesting... So cutting off adjacent corners will mean they share one corner, and eliminate one edge? This is more complex than it seems at first

Comment: Since imgur being blocked in Turkey, I can not see the image. Can you please send an alternate image link

Comment: @JoKing yes that is correct.

Comment: @WindmillCookies I'm sorry, I didn't know that. I've used a different host now.

Comment: Thank you, Now I am able to give the question a try

Comment: For example, may I use 0 for A, 1 for C, 2 for B, 3 for D, 4 for E, 5 for G, 6 for F, 7 for H? Or should I keep the order of ABCDEFGH?

Comment: I decided that it's okay to rearrange the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
3R×L+“©®€‘ɓŒcn/€§ċ1;`Żạ
```

A monadic Link. Input is a list of corners of the cube as Cartesian co-ordinates (cube aligned with the co-ordinate system). Output is a list of integers, `[faces, corners, edges]`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9846PB0H@1HDXMOrTy07lHTmkcNM05OPjopOU8fyDm0/Ei3oXXC0d0Pdy38//9/dLSBDhDG6oBpQyBtCKZjAQ)**

#### How?

```
3R×L+“©®€‘ɓŒcn/€§ċ1;`Żạ - Link: list of lists, C          e.g. [[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]] -- this could represent "FHGA"
3R                      - range of 3                           [1,2,3]
   L                    - length of C                          4
  ×                     - multiply                             [4,8,12]
     “©®€‘              - list of code-page indices            [6,8,12]
    +                   - add                                  [10,16,24]
          ɓ             - start a new dyadic chain, f(C,X) where X is the above result
           Œc           - pairs of C                           [[[0,1,1],[1,1,0]],[[0,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[0,1,1],[0,0,0]],[[1,1,0],[1,1,1]],[[1,1,0],[0,0,0]],[[1,1,1],[0,0,0]]]
              /€        - reduce €ach with:
             n          -   (vectorising) not equal?           [[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
                §       - sum each                             [2,1,2,1,2,3]
                 ċ1     - count ones                           2
                   ;`   - concatenate with itself              [2,2]
                     Ż  - prepend a zero                       [0,2,2]
                      ạ - absolute difference with X           [10,14,22]
```

---

If the corners must be "ordered" as they are in the question then this works with integers 0-7 as A-H for 25 bytes: [`` 3R×L+“©®€‘ɓŒc^/€ḟ2<5S;`Żạ ``](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9qZWxsef//M1LDl0wr4oCcwqnCruKCrOKAmMmTxZJjXi/igqzhuJ8yPDVTO2DFu@G6of///1swLDEsMl0) (reduces using XOR, filters out twos, then counts those less than five).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```perl6
{6+@_,|((2,3 X*4+@_)X-(@_ X~@_)∩~<<ords "% 286
>C/")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2kzbIV6nRkPDSMdYIULLBMjTjNDVcIhXiKgDMh91rKyzsckvSilWUJJXVTCyMOPiE7Fz1lfSrP1fnFipkKYRHatpzQVlGiCzdcxQeTrGKHxDDL4RWOQ/AA)

Uses the numbers `0` to `7` to represent the corners. I probably should have matched them up to the same order as in the question... oops? Outputs a list in the order `faces, corners, edges`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>48</s> 45 bytes

```
≔Ｅθ↨℅ι²η≔⊘№⭆η⭆ηΣＥι↔⁻§λξν1ηＩＥ⟦⁶⁻⁸η⁻¹²η⟧⁺ι×⊕κＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NC4JAEIbv/YrF0wgbpEEEnsxLQpJQt@iw6eIurWO6q/jvt1Xz0BwGHub9mEKwrmiYsjbWWlYIGftAS8mJaQ7XrpTIFEifktB3S/jR5qc7MzXwEpKmRwM300msJqug5B/6eo6UlMQvDZnEXkNsUiz5CIqS0aWiPw8lXuCtLbnLMJAwbWb740DJ4j1O9xWCcKInJbly5DrusuYaUiw6XnM07sG3E184VkZAu/RE1u6Cvd0O6gs) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses digits `0-7` to represent the letters `ABDCEFHG` in the diagram. Outputs in the order faces, corners, edges. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅθ↨℅ι²η
```

Take the ASCII code of each character and convert it to base 2.

```
≔⊘№⭆η⭆η
```

Take the cartesian product of the list of base 2 numbers with itself.

```
ΣＥι↔⁻§λξν1η
```

XOR the pairs of base 2 numbers together and sum the number of 1 bits. Count how many pairs have a sum of 1 and divide that by 2. This gives the number of coincident corners.

```
ＩＥ⟦⁶⁻⁸η⁻¹²η⟧⁺ι×⊕κＬθ
```

Calculate and print the number of faces, corners and edges.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 84 bytes

```javascript
a=>[a.map(u=>a.map(v=>j-=!!'ABCDAEFGHEFBCGHD'.match(u+v),n++,j+=2),n=j=6)|2+j,n+j,n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i46US83sUCj1NYOwiiztcvStVVUVHd0cnZxdHVz93B1c3J293BRB0qXJGdolGqXaerkaWvrZGnbGgFZtlm2Zpo1RtpZQEEgjv2fnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RphEdq6lpzYUmpu6ojkNYR90Zn5SOuhtuaSf8up2gJriAlfwHAA)